# How to dynamically load correct version of 3rd party unmanaged control in c#

Tags: c#, load, version, unmanaged, tlb

My app is a c# plug in to a 3rd party unmanaged app. I have a windows form with one of their controls (an AxInterop) that depends on one of their unmanaged dlls. Their 2015 version of the same control depends on a different type library file (eg. abc.tlb is now 123.tlb), but they both support the same interface.

I don't want to create separate builds.

How can I get my code to use the ABC.tlb for the earlier versions and use 123.tlb for the 2015 version?

Can you load tlb files like assemblies at start up?

thanks

Comment: That makes no sense.  The .tlb file is the type library that's used at compile-time.  You must therefore recompile your app with a new type library reference.

Comment: I've used dynamics before and reflection so I don't have to reference the same dll used by this control.  The difference here now is that I'm using the control which is referencing the dll and I am looking for a way to get it to find the new dll for 2015. So maybe thinking I need to load a different tlb I just need to load that new dll at start up. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved it using dynamics after all. The AxInterop control was a red herring. The control has a property that is of the type that changed for 2015. I used dynamics to get the property from the third party's workspace object and then set the property to that value. My project has no references to ABC or 123.